# How to denote mass and distance approaches to zero?

Tags: mass, conventions, notation, mathematics, distance

I saw in a physics book that one denotes that mass and distance approaches to zero as $m\to 0$ and $d\to 0$. Is this correct or should one denote these as [one-sided limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) $m\to 0^+$ and $d\to 0^+$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both mass and distance are non-negative, by experience and definition, so there is no confusion in writing $\rightarrow 0$ instead of $\rightarrow 0^+$